# Vuelidate check array has items on blur

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuelidate, vue-select

I am using [nuxt-vue-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-vue-select) to allow users to select multiple objects form an array `locations` and then I want to use [Vuelidate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuelidate) to try and validate that at least one item in the array has been selected/set on blur however I can not get `vuelidate` do do this. What am I doing wrong here?

**Template**

```
<b-form-group label="Locations" label-for="locations">
    <client-only>
        <v-select
          v-model="userCopy.locations"
          name="locations"
          filterable
          multiple
          placeholder="Select locations"
          label="label"
          :options="locations"
          :class="{ 'is-invalid': v.form.locations.$error }"
          @blur="v.form.locations.$each[index].$touch()"
        />
    </client-only>
</b-form-group>
```

**Script**

```
data() {
    return {
        form:{
            locations: []
        }
    }
},

validations() {
    return {
      form: {
        locations: {
          $each: {
            required
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

**Array data**

```
  { label: 'Avon' },
  { label: 'Bedfordshire' },
  { label: 'Berkshire' },
  { label: 'City of Brighton and Hove' },
  { label: 'City of Bristol' },
```

Answer (score 1):

According to Vuelidate document(https://vuelidate-next.netlify.app/validators.html#required),

you should use `required` to check if the array is empty rather than `minLength`

Therefore your code should be like:

```
validations() {
  return {
    form: {
      locations: {
        required,
        $each: { ... //validation for each item }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

For vuelidate you have to use the same filed name as $data, so you need to replace the name `form` of validations' object to `userCopy` at first, and apply minLength for your locations length:

```
validations() {
    return {
      userCopy: { // change this
        locations: {
          // ... to try and validate that at least one item in the array
          // use minLength to do that
          minLength: minLength(1)
          $each: {
            required
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

To deal with array structure, I recommend to try [`form-validation.js`](https://github.com/iendeavor/form-validation.js).

Comment: If the user focuses on the input. then navigates away, the error on blur is not registered